# convert json object to array

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object like this coming back as a server response.

```
{"names":["Kreisler","Kreisler","Kreisler"]}
```

I need this object as an array.

Any help?

Comment: Are you using jquery? using the "json" parameter in datatype? provide a little more info please

Comment: yes am using jquery,

Answer (score 4):

Use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var json = '{"names":["Kreisler","Kreisler","Kreisler"]}';
data = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(data['names']); // ["Kreisler", "Kreisler", "Kreisler"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that response data is in `response` variable, use this:

```
var names = response["names"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"names":["Kreisler","Kreisler","Kreisler"]}', function(k, v) {
  console.log(k); // log the current property name, the last is "".
  return v;       // return the unchanged property value.
});
console.log(data.names[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `json` parameter in datatype and your callback argument is called response, then:

```
arrayThatINeed = response.names;
```